# How close a sample is to the Normal distribution (Berry-Esseen Theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

**My question is how can I use the Berry-Esseen Theorem to know how close to the Gaussian distribution is $L$**, where

$$L=nLn(2)+Ln(r_1)+Ln(r_2)+ \cdots + Ln(r_n)$$

$r_i \geq 0$ is a i.i.d. random variable from the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

The mean and variance for $Ln(r_1)$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
  \mathbb{E}[Ln(r_1)]&=&-\frac{\gamma}{2},\\
   \mathbb{E}[(Ln(r_1)-\mathbb{E}[Ln(r_1)])^2]&=&\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[Ln(r_1)]=\frac{\pi^2}{24},\\
\end{eqnarray}

Where $\gamma=0.57721$.

> **Berry-Esseen Theorem:** Let $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ be real i.i.d. random variables satisfying
> \begin{eqnarray*}
>    \mathbb{E}[Z_i]&=&v,\\
>    \mathbb{E}[(Z_i-v)^2]&=&\sigma^2>0,\\
>    \mathbb{E}[|Z_i-v|^3]&=&\rho<\infty.
> \end{eqnarray*}
> Then let
> \begin{equation*}
>     Z:=Z_1+\cdots+Z_n,
> \end{equation*}
> and let $W \thicksim \mathcal{N}(vn,\sigma^2n)_\mathbb{R}$ be a real gaussian with mean $vn$ and variance $\sigma^2n$. Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,\begin{equation*}
>     \left| Pr[Z\leq x]- Pr[W \leq x] \right|\leq \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}},
> \end{equation*}
> where $C$ is some universal constant.

Comment: By $Ln(x)$ you mean $\ln(x)$ ?  But more to the point: in what way doesn't your last displayed equation actually answer your question?  I mean, given everything you state, what is your actual question?

Comment: Yes, $\ln(x)$. I have a sum of random variables, and I`d like to know if this sum has a distribution close to the normal distribution. So my idea is to use the berry-Esseen theorem to assures that $L$ is close to the normal distribution. My problem with using the theorem appears because of the $n\ln(2)$ in the sum.

Comment: So let $Z_i=\ln(2 r_i)$ in your application of B-E, with corresponding modification to $v,\sigma,\rho$.